# How to hint content manager chooser to open directly on a selectable position with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, android-11

When you use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`to pick the permission to a path where to store files in Android 11, the default Android content manager by default opens on a recently used path and the button ***"USE THIS FOLDER"*** for some reason doesn't even appear at all, even if this path is an accessible path, unless the user manually move through paths to go to a suitable position (or returns in the path opened by default moving through directories if this is a selectable position).

E.g.
Assume the latest path used by an user was *Documents*. When I ask the user to select a path where to allow the app to save the files, with

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
```

this is what appears:

[image]

As you can see there is no ***"USE THIS FOLDER"*** blue button.

Now if the user select the superfolder path from here and enter again in *Documents* this is what He sees:

[image]

Now the ***"USE THIS FOLDER"*** button is available.

This is totally senseless and it's dreadful for the user experience, and many users certainly end up uninstalling the app bothered and confused.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is possible to pass to the intent some hint in order to open the content manager `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` view directly in a specific path available in all Android devices storage (e.g. *Documents*) with the ***"USE THIS FOLDER"*** button available on the opening of the chooser?

Comment: The only thing possible on Android 10 and 11 is opening in`external storage: primary partion` and `external storage: sd card`.

Comment: @blackapps Do you mean as hint to `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`?

Comment: No. I just mean that if you use Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE you can let it open on those two partitions. Not in subfolders or something like that.

Comment: @blackapps In what way? If I call `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` as shown in the question by default it's shown latest used path (not even selectable) rather than root of one of these partitions.

Comment: I have no code at hand at the moment. Tomorrow there is another day.

Comment: @blackapps any update? :)

Comment: @AndreaF Did you ever get this problem fixed? I am dealing with the same thing. Any update(s) you have will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: any update?? I'm looking to find the solution of this .